# Callback function is getting executed before the original function

Tags: javascript, callback

I am writing a snippet for demonstrating callback function. I have a function alpha, in which I am passing a function beta as callback. What I assume is that first alpha must be executed, and after all work is done, beta must be executed. Why I am seeing beta getting executed first, as per callback, they execute when all work is done -- that I learnt.

```js
function alpha() {
  alert('hi');
}

function beta() {
  alert('hello');
}

alpha(beta());
```

**Expecting:**

hi then hello

**Result:**

hello then hi

Comment: you need to call beta from alpha. you can do that by name, or by passing it without calling it inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't do what you think:

```
alpha(beta());
```

This invokes `beta` immediately and then passes the *result* of `beta()` to the invokation of `alpha`.  And since `beta` doesn't return anything, that result is `undefined`.

What you want is to send the function itself as the callback, not the result of executing the function:

```
alpha(beta);
```

**Additionally** in your `alpha` you would need to actually *call* the callback:

```
function alpha(callback){
    alert('hi');
    callback();
}
```

Comment: but now hello does not get printed at all ;(

Comment: @Deadpool: I just updated the answer.  You also weren't calling the callback anywhere.